# Laravel save eloquent model with relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-livewire

Sorry if this is something really simple but I haven't been able to find an answer after hours of searching...

I have this object with relations:

```
    $this->versionSelected = new StyleVersions();
    $this->versionSelected = StyleVersions::with([
        'colourways.colourway_yarns.yarns.spinners',
    ])->find($id);
```

Which is edited using wire:model:

```
wire:model="versionSelected.name"
```

and then verified:

```
protected $rules = [
    'versionSelected.name' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.factories_id' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.yarn_transportation_cost' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.yarn_transportation_currency' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.accessories_cost' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.accessories_currency' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.transport_cost' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.gmt_transportation_currency' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.cmt' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.gmt_weight' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.area_office_commission' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.notes' => 'required',
    'versionSelected.style_version_prices' => 'required',
];
```

I then want to save that object to the database, but it is having issues with the relations.

```
$this->versionSelected->save();
```

When this is called I get the followin error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'style_version_prices' in 'field list' (SQL: update `style_versions` set `style_version_prices` = [{"id":10,"style_versions_id":4,"price":54.7,"notes":"Quo dolorum ab dolores.","created_at":"2022-02-25T10:19:23.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-02-25T10:19:23.000000Z"},{"id":18,"style_versions_id":4,"price":75,"notes":"Voluptatibus aut nihil.","created_at":"2022-02-25T10:19:23.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-02-25T10:19:23.000000Z"},

Is there a way I can update without it looking at the relations, which I can update separately? Thanks in advance! =D

EDIT:

Here is the code for the style_versions table:

```
        Schema::create('style_versions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->foreignId('styles_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('factories_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->text('name')->nullable();
        $table->float('yarn_transportation_cost');
        $table->float('gmt_weight');
        $table->float('cmt');
        $table->float('accessories_cost');
        $table->float('transport_cost');
        $table->text('notes')->nullable();
        $table->float('area_office_commission')->default(0);
        $table->float('yarn_cost');

        $table->text('cmt_currency')->nullable();
        $table->text('accessories_currency')->nullable();
        $table->text('yarn_transportation_currency')->nullable();
        $table->text('gmt_transportation_currency')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And the model:

```
class StyleVersions extends Model
```

{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $fillable = [
    'styles_id',
    'factories_id',
    'yarn_transportation_cost',
    'gmt_weight',
    'cmt',
    'accessories_cost',
    'transport_cost',
    'area_office_commission',
    'notes',
    'cmt_currency',
    'accessories_currency',
    'yarn_transportation_currency',
    'gmt_transportation_currency',
    'yarn_cost', 
];

public function styles()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Styles::class);
}
public function factories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Factories::class);
}

public function colourways()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Colourways::class);
}
public function style_version_prices()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StyleVersionPrices::class);
}
```

}

Comment: share scheme of style_versions  table

Comment: Can you add the id from the relations to the with function? Like that: `$this->versionSelected = StyleVersions::with([
        'colourways.id,colourways.colourway_yarns.yarns.spinners',
    ])->find($id);`

Comment: @AqibJaved I have added to the bottom of the question. Thanks!

Comment: @MaikLowrey that throws an error:
    'Call to undefined relationship [id,colourways] on model [App\Models\Colourways]. '

Comment: How are you saving the `style_version_prices` ? there have no column in your `style_versions` table. what is the schema of StyleVersionPrices?